# How could I get the result of TemplateMatching using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I have two images a.jpg(src 1000*1000) and b.jpg(tpl 100*100).

```
Mat a=imread("a.jpg");//1000*1000
Mat b=imread("b.jpg");//100*100
...
double minVal; double maxVal; 
...
matchTemplate(a, b, result, 0 );
minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat());

printf("minVal=%f \n maxVal=%f \n", minVal,maxVal);
```

How to get the best matching(or adjustments),someone can help me,thanks :)

Comment: At a first glance i would say your code is correct, so: What is not working? What is your expected output? What do you get?

Comment: Can you posr your sample template and src please?

Comment: I want judgement matching is seccuss,ture or false. What would you suggest ?

Comment: @Micka  My code is working  fine, i want to know how to  judgement matching is seccuss of both images.:)

Comment: Seems similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715830/success-of-template-matching-with-opencv?rq=1

Comment: @AndreySmorodov :),It's great,I love you so much and more

Comment: in `result` there  is a value for each position of your source image. The values tell you how good the template is represented int hat position! So the minVal or maxVal (depending on the comparisionmethod you used) tells you how good the best found value is and the position is minLoc or maxLoc ;)

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your advise.I have understood your explanation.:)